# Error message with sklearn function " 'RocCurveDisplay' has no attribute 'from_predictions' "

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I am trying to use the sklearn function RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions as presented in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions.
I run the function like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay

true = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

prediction = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.])

RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions(true,prediction)
plt.show()
```

I get the error message "AttributeError: type object 'RocCurveDisplay' has no attribute 'from_predictions' ".

Is this a version problem? I am using the latest one, 0.24.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your version `0.24.1` is not the latest version, You'll need to upgrade to scikit-learn `1.0` as `from_predictions` is supported in `1.0`

You can upgrade using:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this version is only supported for python 3.7 and above